# Using COALESCE within a FULL JOIN, returning duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to link different keys together.
The following problem the projid key has to be joint on ServiceObjectId and on TaskId. The easiest way to do this seems to use an or statement.

So:

```
FULL JOIN PROJTABLE
    ON PROJTABLE.PROJID = MSM_TASKTABLE.PROJID
    or PROJTABLE.PROJID = MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE.SERVICEOBJECTID
```

However the performance is dreadful
Thats way i tried to use the COALESCE function.
As shown in the following script

```
INSERT INTO AR_BI_sleutels (DataareaId,PartyId,ContractId,RentalObjectId,ObjectId,ServiceObjectId,ServiceCallId,TaskId,ProjId)
Select
    ,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
    ,PMCCONTRACTOBJECT.RENTALOBJECTID
    ,PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
    ,MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE.SERVICEOBJECTID
    ,MSM_SVCCALLTABLE.SVCCALLID
    ,MSM_TASKTABLE.TASKID
    ,COALESCE(TASK.PROJID,SERVICE.PROJID) AS PROJID
From PMCCONTRACT
FULL JOIN PMCCONTRACTOBJECT
    ON PMCCONTRACTOBJECT.RENTALOBJECTID = PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID
        AND PMCCONTRACTOBJECT.DATAAREAID = PMCCONTRACT.DATAAREAID
FULL JOIN MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE
    ON MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE.EXTOBJECTID = PMEOBJECT.OBJECTID
FULL JOIN MSM_SVCCALLTABLE
    ON MSM_SVCCALLTABLE.SERVICEOBJECTID = MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE.SERVICEOBJECTID
FULL JOIN MSM_TASKTABLE
    ON MSM_TASKTABLE.SVCCALLID = MSM_SVCCALLTABLE.SVCCALLID
FULL JOIN PROJTABLE as Task
    ON Task.PROJID = MSM_TASKTABLE.PROJID
FULL JOIN PROJTABLE as Service
    ON service.PROJID = MSM_SERVICEOBJECTTABLE.SERVICEOBJECTID
WHERE (PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS is null OR PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTSTATUS <> 5)
        AND COALESCE(TASK.PROJID,SERVICE.PROJID) IS NOT NULL
```

However this statement returns duplicate values.
Any ideas on how i could make the working correctly?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `COALESCE` in the `WHERE`, I would use boolean logic: `AND (TASK.PROJID IS NOT NULL OR SERVICE.PROJID IS NOT NULL)`. Your `WHERE` isn't going to be creating duplicates, a `WHERE` filters results not adds them. I suspect the problem is that you are using `FULL JOIN`s everywhere; so the entire contents of every table is returned and the only filtered based on your `WHERE`. Which raises the question, why *are* you using `FULL OUTER JOIN`s? It may well be the problem goes away if you use an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`. Impossible to tell with sample and expected data.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results -- preferably with a simplified query.  `FULL JOIN`s are tricky, particularly when trying to filter the data.  They are almost never actually needed.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you understand different types of `JOIN`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/3484879

Comment: I have never seen so many full joins, they aren't used very often. How can you have a "contract object" without a "contract"? (that is probably an inner join, not a full join). Without sample data (from each table, individually) we can do very little to help.

Comment: additionally the query you have supplied will not work, there is a spurious comma after select: `select , PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID` and there is no join for `PMEOBJECT`

Answer (score 1):

`FULL JOIN` is an `OUTER JOIN` type which means *keep rows from both sets even if the lookup condition is not satisfied*. Originally, with `PROJTABLE` `FULL JOIN`'d *once*, you have fed all rows of `PROJTABLE` *once* to the final result. You changed the logic by `FULL JOIN`ing `PROJTABLE` *twice*, so you have fed all rows of `PROJTABLE` *twice* to the final result. Now I guess that using `COALESCE` you thought that it is similar to an OR condition in your original lookup (or see my PS), but it will not do what needs to be done now: you don't want to keep all rows of `PROJTABLE` *twice*. You need to use `distinct` in the final query, or in a subquery that collects rows only from `PROJTABLE`, or you might think over if you really need all rows from `PROJTABLE` and maybe change the `JOIN` type.

*PS*: `COALESCE(TASK.PROJID,SERVICE.PROJID) IS NOT NULL` states *remove from the final result if there were neither a TASK nor a SERVICE match (because NULL can only be returned by `COALESCE` if all args are null)* - it is not your original statement.